# How can I return just a NSHttpUrlResponse status code from NSUrlSession

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

How can I return just a NSHttpUrlResponse status code from NSUrlSession.
I am very new to this language.So,If there is other better practice please let me know.My code is right below here.

```
//Method to return a status code
        func responseCode() -> Int{
        var responseCode : Int=0
        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
        // get news feed url
        let url = NSURL(string: baseUrl)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
//create request
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        request.HTTPMethod = httpMethod
//check null value
        if (bodyData != "") {
            request.HTTPBody =  bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
        }
        if (auth != "") {
            print("Token Auth : \(auth)")
            request.addValue("bearer \(self.auth)", forHTTPHeaderField:      "Authorization")
        }
        print("request : \(request)")

//How to return a Integer from this below function
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request,     completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            print("Error\(error)")
            if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                print("HttpReponse\(httpResponse.statusCode)")
                // Get a status code and assign it in a variable
                responseCode = httpResponse.statusCode
            }
        })
        task.resume()
//Return a response code in ViewController but it just return a initial set value that is 0
        return responseCode
        }
//Return a responseCode in ViewController but it just return a    initial set value that is 0
    return responseCode
    }
```

Comment: I have saw this previously but could not understand much because i am very new to this language. Can you please edit on my code.

Answer (score 3):

Here `session.dataTaskWithRequest` is an asynchronous task i.e. it will be called in another thread (other than the main thread) and its closure will be called when you get response from server.

So what you are doing here is you are trying to return `responseCode` which is called in main thread i.e. it will return before you have got any response.

You should use completion handler:

```
func responseCode(completion: (statusCode:Int) -> ()){
        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {

            let url = NSURL(string: baseUrl)
            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request,completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
                print("Error\(error)")

                if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {

                    print("HttpReponse\(httpResponse.statusCode)")
                    // Get a status code and assign it in a variable
                    completion(statusCode: httpResponse.statusCode)

                }
            })
            task.resume()
        }
    }
```

Use this function as below:

```
responseCode { (statusCode) -> () in
            print("Status Code:\(statusCode)")
    }
```

Comment: I have called this function in this manner         
           connection.responseCode({
            statusCode -> Void in
            print("ResponseCode \(statusCode)")
        })
is this a right way because m not getting a value.

Comment: Have you set the `bodyData` and `auth` in your code because i removed some of your code just to focus on the `handler`

Comment: Ya that thing i have done . even i have a print code at the top of the function even that print is not shown inside the log.

Comment: then you are not calling the function properly use breakpoints and check whether it's called or not

Comment: Sorry, well i have not call this function inside view did load that's why the function is not returning a value.Thank you so much brother..thanks a lot once again.I wish i could vote u :)